# Wordpress shop page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, themes

[image]

Hoping someone can be able to assist. So I am working on a Wordpress site that has woocommerce, my concern is that the shop page uses its own theme, and I want it to be all the same (hope I am making sense) for an example my shop page header (including menu responsiveness) is completely different to the rest of the site. How can I fix this? I am not really good at coding hoping someone will be able to provide a more understandable solution. Thanks

Comment: Please provide more information like which theme you are using, which editor you are using, So you will get accurate answer.

Comment: Or may be url of website or just a screenshot.

Comment: I am using the astra theme with the elementor page editor

Comment: https://www.cedarmotors.co.za/

Answer (score 0):

You can customize `Woocommerce` shop page by editing `Woocommerce` shop page template as described on the below articles.

- https://www.woothemes.com/2014/08/five-quick-woocommerce-customization-tips/
- https://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/
- https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/tree/2.5.0/templates

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to solve the issue with its document.

> https://wpastra.com/elementor-woocommerce-theme/